# postgresql: .pgpass not working

Tags: bash, postgresql, database-backups

I have created a `.pgpass` file in my home directory which looks like this

`localhost:5432:somedb:someuser:somepass`

I am using a shell script which creates a directory and puts a pg_dump of `somedb` there :

```
mkdir directory
pg_dump somedb > directory/somefile.dump
```

It still prompts for the password.

Where is the mistake here ?

Comment: Did you try specifying the host & user?  `pg_dump -U someuser -h localhost somedb > directory/somefile.dump`

Comment: Yes a really stupid mistake. Specified the user and it works :D
Thanks

Comment: I was passing -W as the option (which implies "force password prompt"). Ensure that you don't have this (in addition to the accepted answer)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Did you try specifying the host, user, & db?

```
pg_dump -U someuser -h localhost somedb > directory/somefile.dump
```

Comment: Isn't the .pgpass file supposed to eliminate the need to specify a host and a user?

Comment: @IanHunter No, the purpose of supplying the username and host in the pgpass file is to create matching criteria.  "When this username and host are supplied, use this password". It can only perform this match if you give it a username and host to match with,

Comment: @JHixson - I like your explanation, but this is the first time I've seen the .pgpass file described this way - can you provide a reference for that explanation?

Comment: @JohnPrior sure, the documentation for the Pgpass file: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/libpq-pgpass.html `The file .pgpass in a user's home directory or the file referenced by PGPASSFILE can contain passwords to be used if the connection requires a password.`

Note how it only mentions being able to supply passwords.  it cannot be used to supply anything *but* passwords.  The things that you put in the file with the password are documented as "match criteria" for purposes of looking up a password.

Comment: @JohnPrior a line from the documentation that better illustrates the functionality: `The password field from the first line that matches the current connection parameters will be used.`

Comment: I'm insisting on the fact that -h IS important, especially if it's not localhost...

Comment: database must be mentioned in pgpass file too

Comment: Or you can use only the .pg_service.conf file, if you are using only one db user and schema. Define all the information (ip, port db name, user name and password) under given service name. Set file location in PGSERVICEFILE environment variable and service name in PGSERVICE variable.

Answer (score 45):

1. Create .pgpass file with content

> host:5432:somedb:someuser:somepass

2. set the permissions

> sudo chmod 600 .pgpass

3. Set the file owner as the same user using which you logged in :

> sudo chown login_username:login_username .pgpass

4. Set PGPASSFILE environment variable :

> export PGPASSFILE='/home/user/.pgpass'

Now check by connecting to database :

> psql -h host -U someuser somedb

It did not prompt for a password, and logged-in to postgresql.

Comment: In my case "sudo chown login_username:login_username .pgpass" did the trick.

Comment: Thank you for the details answer. I forgot to specify the `-U <username>` option and it kept asking for the password.

Answer (score 26):

Although question has already been answered and accepted, it may also happen that permissions on .pgpass file are not properly set.  It has to have the world and group access disallowed:

```
/bin/chmod 0600 ~/.pgpass
```

Answer (score 22):

[`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) ([startup.c](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/bin/psql/startup.c)) calls [`PQconnectdbParams`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PQCONNECTDBPARAMS) ([fe-connect.c](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/98719af6c2e30d538cd05cfe044f58ba4067b52b/src/interfaces/libpq/fe-connect.c#L612-L623)), and then [`passwordFromFile`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/98719af6c2e30d538cd05cfe044f58ba4067b52b/src/interfaces/libpq/fe-connect.c#L6838-L6960) is called. Here’s a checklist to make sure the pgpass file will be used:

1. Make sure the flags `--password`/`-W` and `password=` in the [connection string](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING) are unset. Otherwise, the pgpass file will not be used.
2. Make sure the environment variable `PGPASSWORD` is unset (`echo $PGPASSWORD`). Otherwise, the pgpass file will not be used.
3. Make sure the [pgpass file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html) is in the right location (`$PGPASSFILE` or default `~/.pgpass` or `%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf`)
4. Make sure the passfile is not readable, writable, or executable by group or other (e.g. `chmod 600 ~/.pgpass`); otherwise `psql` will print a warning.
5. Make sure the passfile is a file (not a symlink); otherwise `psql` will print a warning.
6. Make sure the passfile is readable by the `psql` user (e.g. `cat ~/.pgpass`); otherwise `psql` will ignore it without warning. Make sure that it is owned by the user, and that all its ancestor directories are executable by the user.
7. Make sure that the pgpass file has the correct format `hostname:port:database:username:password` ([The Password File](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html), [`passwordFromFile`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/98719af6c2e30d538cd05cfe044f58ba4067b52b/src/interfaces/libpq/fe-connect.c#L6838-L6960)). Each field (other than password) can be `*`. The characters `:` and `\` must be escaped `\:` and `\\` (even in password). The password ends at `:` or the end of the line and can include any byte other than `\r`, `\n`, or `\0`. Any lines that aren’t formatted right or don’t match the host and user are ignored without warning as if they were comments.
8. Make sure the hostname, port, dbname, username of the line in the pgpass file match the server or are `*`. The server’s “pwhost” that is checked is the `host` name if non-empty, or the `hostaddr` ip address. Otherwise, the line will be ignored without warning.

Unfortunately, there is no logging within these files, so if this doesn’t help, then you may need to compile `psql` and `libpq` yourself and run it in a debugger.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was trying to use * all over the place and it just wasn't working. So if you are trying t ouse wildcards in the pgpass file, I recommend against it. PoS code.

Comment: Thank you so so much, I spent 2 days setting this file and getting password error, you saved me.

Comment: Thanks! For me, change from `localhost:5432:squared_development:squared:squared` to `localhost:5432:*:squared:squared` did the 'do not ask for password' trick.

Answer (score 5):

Check the owner of the .pgpass file. Just lost half an hour to find out I had created my .pgpass file with sudo. The command for my user and location was `chown postgres:postgres /var/lib/pgsql/.pgpass`.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was I already set PGPASSWORD environment variable (to a wrong password), so `psql` was picking that instead of what's inside `.pgpass`

Answer (score 0):

If your password happens to include a colon, you have to escape it by preceding it with a \ in order for the password to be recognised.