# psql prompts for user password despite PGPASSFILE var defined

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-10.04, psql

I have an environment variable `PGPASSFILE` declared pointing to the location of my `.pgpass` file.

```
>echo $PGPASSFILE
/somedir/.pgpass
```

As per [this doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html), the permission stamp of the file is proper to not expose the file to anyone else:

```
>ls -la /somedir
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2014-06-25 17:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 2014-06-25 16:37 ..
-rw------- 1 root root  354 2014-06-25 16:43 .pgpass
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   30 2014-06-25 16:37 .pgpass_path
```

The file looks about right:

```
  1 localhost:*:*:postgres:blabla
  2 localhost:*:somedb:somedb_master:blabla
  3 localhost:*:somedb:somedb_rw:blabla
```

However, when I try to invoke psql, it still prompts me for password:

```
>psql -h localhost -d somedb -U somedb_rw
Password for user somedb_rw:
```

The connection succeeds when I enter password but I shouldn't be prompted.  Any idea what may be wrong?  This is on Ubuntu 10.04 VM.  On my Mac host, this same configuration works without prompting.

Comment: From this example, it looks like you have a .pgpass in a directory named .pgpass?  So, /somedir/.pgpass/.pgpass?  If so, I think your $PGPASSFILE var needs to be updated.

Comment: no, the var actually needs to point to the file, not the directory where it is

Comment: Exactly.  Your echo shows `/somedir/.pgpass`, but then you do a `ls -la /somedir/.pgpass` and it shows a file owned by root with the same name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [postgresql: .pgpass not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786011/postgresql-pgpass-not-working)